# Java structures for storing chess moves

Tags: java, data-structures, chess

I have an Integer[64] of numbers 0 - 6 which say what type of chess piece is there. I have a Boolean[64] of what color each place is. I need to be able to save them as (Strings?) and save them for later use, but I need a fast and efficient way. As of now I am looping through both arrays and creating a 64char String, but I make a few million of them because my chess AI looks deep into the game. Thoughts?

Comment: I would keep them in the array and use an idex to specify a certain variable, instead of "inflating" an array to (redundant) variables. Consider a multidimensional array so you can do row-column lookup as well.

Comment: you need to come up with better description of the problem. define "fast and efficient" for example

Comment: I will be creating and storing a few million of these (whatever i store them as) in a hashmap and i would need fast access to them

Answer (score 1):

First of all you should redefine your data structure.

Instead of two arrays with integer and booleans you can define one array

```
byte[64] field;
```

Then add two methods that retrieve the information about the type and the color:

```
public int getType(int fieldNo) {
   # this returns the first three bits (int 0-6)
   return field[fieldNo] & 0x07;
}

public boolean getColor(int fieldNo) {
   # this returns the fourth bit 
   return (field[fieldNo] & 0x08) > 0;
}
```

You can now save the complete chess field just by writing/reading the fields array:

```
public byte[] readField(String file) throws IOException {
    byte[] field = new short[64];
    try (DataInputStream stream = new DataInputStream(new FileInputStream(file)); ) {
         stream.readFully(field,0,64);
    }
    return field;
}
public void writeField(String file, byte[] field) throws IOException {
    try (DataOutputStream stream = new DataOutputStream(new FileOutputStream(file)); ) {
         stream.write(field,0,64);
    }
    return field;
}
```

This saves a complete field in 64 bytes.

More improvements:

- Compress the 64 byte filed when saving more than one field to one file. Compression should be good because most of your bytes have value 0.
- Instead of using byte[64] you can use byte[32] only and map the information to the first / last 4 bits of one byte.

Comment: Please post a comment when you downvote my post. Otherwise it's bad style :-(

Comment: I'm not the down voter, but you provided a reduced memory solution when the problem is processor speed.